# Setup redirects for product links after migrating from wordpress to opencart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, opencart

I am migrating from woocommerce to opencart and I want to keep my SEO. But there is a problem with that because the url patterns of the two platforms differ. For example woocommerce uses **site.com/product/my-product** and when I move that to opencart it changes to **site.com/my-category/my-product** or if I enter in the product from other page like the home it just adds the product slug to the url. If there is a link to the product in **site.com** and I click it it will lead me to **site.com/my-product** etc. I have many products for which I want redirects, so I can keep my SEO. How can that be done ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you look at the extension:
https://github.com/barbaris-in/OpenCart-Custom-Url-Redirect

also premium https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=24029

Create a list of OLD and NEW URL and import it using CSV. So SEO will work perfectly fine for you without any 404 page.